# Saving an NSDictionary of NSArrays of custom objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdictionary, save

I have a dictionary (it's mutable if that makes a difference) which contains nsarrays, which in turn contain (subclass of NSObject)s
I have implemented initWithCoder and encodeWithCoder like this:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super init];
    self.Title = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"Title"];
    self.SiteAPIURL = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"SiteAPIURL"];
    self.ID = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"ID"];
    return self;
}

-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.Title forKey:@"Title"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.SiteAPIURL forKey:@"SiteAPIURL"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.ID forKey:@"ID"];
}
```

But it doesn't save properly when I do `[dictionary writeToFile:savepath atomically:YES];`
So what am I doing wrong, and what exactly is serialization and do I need I need to use NSKeyedArchiver or something?

Comment: were you able to figure this out? I have the same exact data structure (different custom objects in the array of course) and I have been trying to implement saving my dictionary for a couple days now. I have also implemented the initWitCoder and encodeWithCoder in my objects class, and I have tried to use UserDefaults and plists, but I cannot get either to work. Any help appreciated!

Comment: @Ryan, you need to use NSKeyedArchiver and the NSCoding Protocol, see the accepted answer and Apple docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[NSDictionary writeToFile: atomically:]` uses `NSPropertyListSerialization`, which can only record a subset of primitive objects (numbers, strings, dates and data). So while you could use `NSCoding` along with `NSKeyedArchiver` to archive the objects, another option is to marshal your objects into a string or data representation, store *that* in the property list, and unmarshal them again on loading.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want to use a NSKeyedArchiver

All the info you need can be found here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html