# Serializing a custom object into NSDictionary or NSArray to use NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, serialization, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I've been looking for a way to serialize custom objects with `NSJSONSerialization` avoiding the use of third-party libraries, and I couldn't find any example. Is there any way of "automatically" create an `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` from an object, without having to create it typing in code all the object's member names yourself one by one and setting manually the values? I found a related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235485/saving-an-nsdictionary-of-nsarrays-of-custom-objects), but it is pretty old, things may have now changed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use KVC to ask any object for `dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` which will give you a dictionary representation of the object.

If you need to change the property / key names then you want to do some mapping and (depending on what you're using the JSON for) you may find RestKit useful.